# Activate service worker on local DNS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, service-worker, sw-toolbox

I have a PWA developed in NodeJS and ReactJS. I have used gulp to generate service worker using `sw-toolbox`. The service worker is working when I compile the app and visit `localhost` URL but my app is using apache config and I have a DNS route defined for it in hosts.

File **/etc/hosts**:

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1 localhost myapp.domain.com
```

I have overridden default apache config and enabled my own apache config for the app which looks like:

File **/etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.loc.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName myapp.domain.com
    ProxyPass /a http://microservice.domain.com/a
    ProxyPassReverse /a http://microservice.domain.com/a
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error2.log
    CustomLog /tmp/access.log combined
    Timeout 2400
    ProxyTimeout 2400
</VirtualHost>
```

How to enable service worker locally on my website? I have tried many articles but could not find any answer

Comment: Service workers only run over HTTPS / secure context

Comment: can I register it on http somehow?

Comment: no, it's built into browser standards for security reasons, SSL is cheap and easy to add over the top, use lets encrypt or a proxy in front like cloudflare etc